# What is the correct react syntax for appending to spread attributes

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to add "{ "text" :" to the beginning, and "}" to the end of the string.

I've been looking around and playing with different versions of what's below

`{'{ "text" : "'+{...propName.props}+'" }'}`

Is it even possible to append to a spread attribute?

Adding more information to what Im trying to achieve

An empty `propsName.props` passes down to an `<input type="text"/>`

```
<input
      type="text"
      className="SCSSstuff"
      disabled={loading}
      placeholder="Demo Text"
      autoComplete="off"
      ref="someRef"
      tabIndex={3}
      {...propsName.props}  //<---- 'User Text' gets defined here
      />
```

I need to pass that down to a hidden input

```
<input
      type="hidden"
      disabled={loading}
      {...propsName.props} //<-- I need this output to be { "text" : "User Text" }
      />
```

Comment: Question is little unclear but what does your propsName.props contains ?

Comment: You should use Array#reduce, reduce your array to a string

Comment: @saurssaurav propName.props will contain a user entered value from a text input

Comment: if it is a text input then why use a spread operator. You can use template literals(`). in your case : {text: ${propName.props}}. you can add more of your code and description, so that others can understand and help you.

Comment: added some code, hopefully it clarifies what i'm looking to do

Answer (score 0):

If your props contain user entered value then it should be some primitive type.

You could use template string to achieve the desired result.

```
const propName = {
    props: 'hey'
}
const templateString = `{ text: ${ propName.props } }`
console.log(templateString) // { text: hey }
```

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: Your answer gets me very close!

<input
         type="hidden"
         disabled={loading}
         value={templateString}
         {...propsName.props} <--- This is where I need the full string
         />

Comment: If we knew the input and expected output, we can add more value.

Comment: Updated my question, hopefully it clarifies things